# Regex select only dot but before and after there should not be any number

Tags: regex

How do I select the only dot(.) from the string and before and after there should be no numbers

**My Try**

```
([^0-9])?(\.)([^0-9])?
```

**String**

```
-MEGACLAV-375MG.TAB.
MEGACLAV-625MG.TAB.#
-CALCY-250MG. TAB.
-CALCY-500MG. TAB.
TETAN-AM TAB.
VOGO-0.2MG.TAB. [ ALEMBIC ]
VOGO-0.3MG.TAB. [ ALEMBIC ]
```

**REGEX URL LIVE**

https://regexr.com/4n3ah

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a look-around regex:

```
(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GTrV9d/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\d)`: Negative Lookbehind to assert we don't have a digit at previous position
- `\.`: Match a dot
- `(?!\d)`: Negative Lookahead to assert we don't have a digit at next position